# Get a subset of several alphabetically ordered files in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Let's assume I have a group of files "aab.md", "aac.md", "aad.md" ... "csdw.md". Content/filenames are actually in (non-latin) utf-8. They can be sorted alphabetically.

How can I get in Bash a subset of those files starting with e.g. "aad.md" and upwards?

Comment: If you sort the full paths to the files, are they still sorted correctly?

Comment: Isn't a simple use of the `name` filter the `find` utility offers suitable?

Comment: @jww - edited, please, remove [on hold].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare -a files
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  filename=${file##*/}
  if [[ ! "$filename" < "aad.md" ]]
  then
    files=("${files[@]}" "$file")
  fi
done < <(find . -name "*.md" -print0)
```

The array `"${files[@]}"` should now contain paths to files whose basename is greater than `aad.md`.

This uses a number of less well-known techniques in bash: arrays, prefix substitution, zero-terminated records (and their reading), and process substitution; so don't hesitate to ask if something is unclear.

Note that `bash` `[[...]]` construct doesn't know about `>=` operator, so we need to improvise with `! ...<...`.

This is almost pure bash, no external commands except `find`. If you accept external commands, `$(basename $file)` is more obvious than `${file##*/}`, but at that point you might as well use `awk`... and if you can use `awk`, why not Ruby?

```
ruby -e "puts Dir['**/*.md'].select{|x| File.basename(x) >= 'aad.md'}"
```